# Horizontal Scaling of Tomcat in Microsoft Azure

Tags: session, tomcat, azure, replication, cluster-computing

I am working on this quiet a while, but still no conclustion.

I want to do horizontal scaling of Tomcat instances in Microsoft Azure (1,2,3,... Tomcat instances for one service). I read lots of articles about session replication, clustering,... with Tomcat. Since Azure does not support Multicasts, there is no easy way to cluster Tomcat. Also sticky sessions is no options, because Azure does round robin load balancing. Setting up two services - one with Terracotta or Apache mod_jk - and the other with Tomcat instances seems overkill for me (if even doable)...

Is this even possible?

Thanks in advance for reading and answering my question. Every comment/idea is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is the new appFabric caching service you could use, or there are examples of using Memcache on Azure, would that help?

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/winazurememcached

Comment: Thank you very much - this looks very interesting, I will try it together with http://code.google.com/p/memcached-session-manager/. Do you have any experience with the winazurememcached?

Comment: Afraid not, but I know Chris Auld has, he's on twitter @cauld

Comment: Thank you very much ;) - a short question: inordner to keep all instances up to date, it is necessary to force tomcat to store every changed session in the database. Is that possible without changing the application's code?

Comment: I'm no java expert by a long shot, but it looks like you can configure tomcat to use jdbc as a session store: http://www.metro-six.com/blog/2010-08-30_tomcat_jdbc_session_persistence

Comment: That's right. I did this. But Tomcat only pulls the session if not known by the Tomcat instance, but does not update it frequently after a change of the session content by the application.

Comment: @fabe I just uploaded a build of memcached-session-manager with non-sticky session support to dropbox: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1439289/memcached-session-manager-1.4.0-SNAPSHOT.jar You can use it together with other 1.3.6 jars mentioned on http://code.google.com/p/memcached-session-manager/wiki/SetupAndConfiguration (e.g. if you want to give kryo a try). To use non-sticky session you must add the attribute sticky="false" to the manager configuration. If you have any questions you're also invited to ask on the mailing list :-) Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

Why do you feel that running 2 services is overkill, exactly? If you have no issue with scaling out to *n* Tomcat instances, adding another service for load distribution is a perfectly acceptable solution in my book. By running that service on a minimum of 2 instances, that service itself meets the Azure SLA requirements: your uptime will be as good as it is going to get on Azure, and you avoid a SPoF (single point of failure).

You could go with a product like terracotta, but it is also pretty straightforward to write a simple socket server to route HTTP sessions back to a particular instance running in Windows Azure. You would have to be aware of node recyles, but that is quite doable.

Be aware that memcached requires an additional Azure service as well (web roles), the appFabric caching service does not (but also has cost associated with it). I do not know Tomcat, but for IIS you can easily move session state from in memory to persisted (either SQL Azure or Azure Storage). Something to be aware of: for high volume sites, the transaction cost to Azure Storage can actually become a cost driver for your deployment if you store session info there. SQL Azure could well be the more cost-effective solution, but on the other hand might not be supported out-of-the-box for your solution.

Comment: First of all i like to thank you for your post. You are Right it is acceptable front that point of view, but i like to avoid a Single point of failure. Do you think terracottA or Apache mod_jk Cannabis be used in azure?

Comment: Updated my answer. I have no experience with either terracotta or Apache, so I cannot help you there.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that you can run Tomcat on Azure. Even if you could (using the virtual machine role) it is probably cheaper to run it on a Linux VM on Amazon EC2.

**Edit**

I see that this is possible using the Tomcat Solution Accelerator. But look at the disclaimer:

> This solution accelerator is provided
>   for informational purposes only and
>   Microsoft or Infosys makes no
>   warranties, either express or implied

This is an unsupported solution. I know that it is often difficult to question management decisions. But using unsupported software for production systems, when a cheaper supported alternative is available, is generally not a good idea.

Comment: You can run Tomcat by the use of Tomcat Solution Accelerator. Azure is set - management decision - not mine - but PaAS has it's advantages ;)

Comment: Tomcat Solution Accelerator is used by Domino Pizza - also Tomcat makes no warranties and is widely used ;)